# How to retrieve the MAC address of a remote IP

Tags: network, ip, mac-address

I have an IP address, and I want to find the corresponding MAC address. The IP address is in the same city, so we're connecting to the same network. How do I find the corresponding MAC address?

Comment: Being in the same city doesn't matter at all. Are you on the same network segment (which means traffic doesn't pass through a router -- eg you are in the same subnet)?

Comment: Being in the same segment isn't much help either. Even the old WD ethernet adapters 30 years ago allowed changing the mac address.

Answer (score 3):

MAC addresses are used for *physical* addressing. Unless you are on the same physical network as the target machine, via something like a switch, hub, or wifi, you are out of luck.

Comment: I'd also add: being on the same (non-routed) VPN this can be possible.